# boxes won't display inline

Tags: html, css

I tried to put all boxes in same line and i did it but there is one problem,
look at the last box, its not in same line.
Can be done by adding one more text line to the last section but i want just 2 lines.

How to fix that?

```css
body {
background: black;
}
.box-container {
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 35px;
  color: white;
  white-space: normal;
}
.fa.rounded.big {
    font-size: 3.5em;
}
.fa.rounded {
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
.box-container section .fa.rounded {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="box-container">
<section class="box"><i class="fa rounded fa-clock-o fa-5x"></i><br><a>This page is created with HTML, CSS and jQuery and beacuse of that, it should be fast.</a></section>
<section class="box"><i class="fa rounded fa-heart-o fa-5x"></i><br><a>Beacuse of bootstrap, UIkit, Animate.css, WOW.js this page is even more awesome!</a></section>
<section class="box"><i class="fa rounded fa-code fa-5x"></i><br><a>There is only 41 lines of code but there will be more things soon!</a></section>
</div>
</body>
```

There are 3 boxes,
make sure you see them all, look at the full page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a

```
vertical-align: top;
```

CSS attribute to the last box. This should fix it.

Comment: Yes, but you answered so fast, i must to wait 10 minutes before accepting it :)

Comment: Now, +1 for your answer and for your comments :D